# Multiple text color in jQuery mobile listview text

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

There is list item in my listview which I want to make it multiple colored:

```
<li class="settings_item" id="lovehate" data-icon="false" style="background: white">
     <a href="#" data-transition="flow" data-icon="false" class="settings_item_a">Love | Hate</a>
</li>
```

The default text color of "Love | Hate" is black. However I want to make "Love" to be red and "Hate" to be black. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could do it. Assuming you don't mind adding a little extra markup.

```
a {
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a .red {
   color:red; 
}

<a href=""> <span class="red">Love</span> | Hate </a>
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/556az/1/

If the text format is always the same, for example `text | text` and you want a more dynamic solution, you could do something like this.

```
var str        = $('a').text();
var textBefore = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("|"));
var pipe       = "|";
var textAfter  = str.split("|").pop();

$( "a" ).wrapInner(function() {
    $(this).text("");
    return "<span class='red'>" + textBefore + "</span>" + pipe + textAfter;
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/556az/6/